# Override ActiveSupport::Concern in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I have a concern that looks like this:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

Three other models use that class methods since they need to the same thing. Then I have a one-off model that needs the method to do something else. I have the set up like this:

```
class FooFoo < ApplicationRecord
  def self.bar
    puts "foo bar"
  end
end
```

Now, when I call `FooFoo.bar`, it would print "foo" instead of "foo bar". How do I override the method defined in the concern? I want it to only run the method defined in my model, `FooFoo`, and not the one in the concern, `Foo`. I looked all over but I don't think I saw what I needed. some help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I also tried this hoping it would work but it didn't:

```
class FooFoo < ApplicationRecord
  def FooFoo.bar # I used FooFoo.bar here instead of self.bar
    puts "foo bar"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to explicitly state that you want `bar` to be a class method...

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do 
    def bar
      puts "bar"
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you can override it...

```
class FooFoo < ApplicationRecord
  def self.bar
    puts "foo bar"
  end
end
```